# Angular generic table with custom cell component for different classes

Tags: angular, components, typescript-generics, ng-content

I want to implement a table with sorting, paging etc. to display lots of different classes, for example `TodoItem`, `User`, etc.

I have created an `ObjectTableComponent<T extends BaseModel>` where all classes that can be displayed extend the `BaseModel`.

The ObjectTableComponent is, basically this:

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor='let row of rows'>
   <td *ngFor='let item of row.items'> <span>{{ item }}</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now, instead of the `<span>{{item}}</span>` I would like to have specialized components displaying, for example, the User's email-address, using, for example a `<app-email-address [email] = "(item as User).email">`

What is the correct way to this in Angular?

(of course, the type cast in the template does not work, but I would like to be able to invert the control, i.e. not have a big list of all possible components with `*ngIf`...)

I have some experience creating wrapper components that use `<ng-content></ng-content>`, but I'm not really sure this is useful here.

Comment: One way I can think of is passing some kind of configuration to the generic table. And in the config, you can specify a `templateRef` for the specific `columnDef`. Then on the generic table side you check if has any `templateRef`. If so, you can use `ngContextOutlet` to display your custom component. This way you can pass any set of components and doesn’t have to be only one.

Comment: Thanks for the `ngContextOutlet` tip, that sound useful!

Comment: Can use that, another approach is to create your components dynamically and inject them as needed: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader